# ViewController loses its properties when I go back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two ViewControllers. The first has `UITableview` that I push data from to the second ViewController. Whenever I go back, the first ViewController loses its properties - Its navigationbar background disappears and for example the sidebar menu does not work either. Is there any way I could reload it while pushing the back button?

Thank you

Comment: How are you going back to the first view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are probably doing your setup in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewWillLoad`. This means that when the view will appear on return, the setup is happening again and perhaps leaving you in an unexpected state. Put breakpoints in your view controller delegate methods and see what order things are being called in and why.